# "Uncaught Error: Class 'Consolidation\Log\LogLevel' not found in /app/vendor/consolidation/log/src/ConsoleLogLevel.php:21"

Tags: drush, 9

I am using lando for the first time and having difficulties. I cloned a git repo and ran the "lando start" and "lando composer install"commands. After that, when I am trying to run the "lando drush cim" command it provides the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Consolidation\Log\LogLevel' not found in /app/vendor/consolidation/log/src/ConsoleLogLevel.php:21

Comment: Does drush work correctly in this repo without lando?  Which version of Drush?  What lando recipe are you using?  On which OS?

Comment: I’ve seen cases where the container PHP version differs from the host version but that hasn’t been taken into account with the Composer target platform setting. https://andy-carter.com/blog/composer-php-platform

Comment: No drush does not work. I am using windows 11. I ended up removing "extends LogLevel" from "class ConsoleLogLevel extends LogLevel {" in the vendor/consolidation/log/src/ConsoleLogLevel.php. I know its not a solution but did it to export my configs for now

Answer (score 0):

Until there is a better way, you need to create manually the class *ConsoleLogLevel*

Inside your app root directory, create a file *vendor/consolidation/log/src/ConsoleLogLevel.php* with the following content :

```
<?php
namespace Consolidation\Log;
class ConsoleLogLevel extends \Psr\Log\LogLevel
{
    const SUCCESS = 'notice';
}
```

Drush commands should now work as expected (tested for a *Drupal* 10.x alpha installation with *Drush* 11.x and *consolidation/log* version 3.x)

Comment: this works, thanks